# Events sent with Measurement Protocol do not set active users

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am trying to send events from a Telegram bot (Java backend) to Google Analytics using Measurement Protocol V4. The event currently looks like this:

```
{
    "client_id": "<telegram_chat_id>",
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "tg_bot_command",
            "params": {
                "command_type": "HELP"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After the event is sent, I see the event and its property on the real-time overview page in the "Event count by Event name" card, but the `client_id` property is nowhere to be seen. And the "Users in last 30 minutes" card remains empty.
I also tried adding the `user_id` parameter to the events, but it also had no effect.

How do I send those events so that they show that users are active?

[G-Analytics page showing logged events, but no users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Fjr.png)

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Kirill Will check today, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution: add engagement_time_msec to event properties

[image]

Comment: Yes, that worked! I already tried sending this parameter as a part of the `user_engagement` event. However, Measurement Protocol does not allow to send a `user_engagement` event as it is considered reserved. I did not realise you could send this param inside a custom event and have it be picked up by Analytics.

Comment: this is brilliant ...Having been researching for hours but the solution is so simple!